# Designated Initializers followed by function name

Tags: c, struct, kernel-module

How does this work, given a function header,

```
ssize_t memory_read(struct file *filp, char *buf, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos);
```

In the struct a designated identifier is used, in this case read followed by the function name, I do understand this is the same as .read = memory_read. However I am unsure of its purpose. Does this provide a method call the memory_read function elsewhere in the code?

```
struct file_operations memory_fops = {
  read: memory_read,
  write: memory_write,
  open: memory_open,
  release: memory_release
};
```

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html

Comment: yes, I saw that but I didn't see anything about the use of functions. Variables yes.

Comment: I misread the question, unable to delete sitting from phone. Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this structure contains a set of function pointers that will be used elsewhere in the program.  Look for something like:

```
memory_fops.read(......)
```

And so on.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I though but was unsure.

Answer (score 0):

The version "name : value" should not be used anymore. This is an gcc extension which has become obsolete with C99 which uses the form ".name = value". If that is a a snippet from a Linux driver, you might stick to it, however, if the style guide demands it. Otherwise I would change it to the standard-compliant version.